# Swift: How to set a different radii for each corner of a UIView or CALayer without explicitly using a CGRect?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uikit, calayer

I am hoping to have different radii for each corner of a `UIView` or `CALayer`, however, without **explicitly** referring to a `CGRect`.

For example, I've done something along the lines of:

```swift
layer.cornerRadius = 4
let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight, .bottomLeft], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 18.0, height: 0.0))
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
layer.mask = maskLayer
```

However, this relies on the `bounds` `CGRect`, so, when my device rotates, everything is broken. I can update the `CGRect` in `layoutSubviews()`, however, this is **delayed** [as shown in this article.](https://marcosantadev.com/calayer-auto-layout-swift/)

If anyone knows how to have different corner radii on the main layer of a `UIView` (so the bounds of the `CALayer` or `UIView` will update automatically) I would appreciate it incredibly!

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.appcoda.com/rounded-corners-uiview/) should help you. From the article:

> In iOS 11, Apple introduced a new property named maskedCorners for the
> Core Animation layer (CALayer). This property is of the type
> CACornerMask, which has 4 possible values:
>
> layerMaxXMaxYCorner – lower right corner
>
> layerMaxXMinYCorner – top right corner
>
> layerMinXMaxYCorner – lower left corner
>
> layerMinXMinYCorner – top left corner

> By default, the value of
> maskedCorners is set to display all the four corners. Now, let’s say
> you just want to round the top corners. You can set maskedCorners to
> the following:
>
> self.view.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner,
> .layerMaxXMinYCorner]

example:

```
lazy var viewWithTopCornersRounded: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.layer.masksToBounds = true
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 4
    view.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner] // top left and top right will be rounded
    return view
}()
```

All 4 corners:

```
yourView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
yourView.layer.masksToBounds = true
yourView.layer.cornerRadius = 4
```